# Materialize autocomplete using php, mysql and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using materialize autocomplete to get suggestion list from my database table. I give the source as php file in which I'm echoing the json file. Below is the code. It's not working. why?

index.php

```
<div class="input-field ">
<input type="text" name="t" id="t" class="autocomplete">
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
source: 'suggest.php?key=%QUERY'

});
});    
</script>
```

suggest.php

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'home_services');

$query= "select * from worker where lname LIKE '%{$key}%'"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($res->num_rows>0){
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
$lname[]= trim($row["lname"]);

}
}
echo json_encode($lname);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Materialize autocomplete doesn't have a `source` option that automatically loads a provided URL.

When you take a look at the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) you can see that you have to initialize your autocomplete like this:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
});
```

The `data` option accepts a string name with an optional icon string.

You will need to pull your autocomplete data before initializing your autocomplete and provide the data to it while initializing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('input', 'input.autocomplete', function() {
        let inputText = $(this).val();

        $.get('suggest.php?key=' + inputText)
            .done(function(suggestions) {
                $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                    data: suggestions
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Also you will need to adapt your `suggest.php` to generate a JSON in the format required by the `data` option of the autocomplete. So you need to change your code like this:

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $lname[trim($row["lname"])] = null;
}
```

EDIT: Also you initialize your array with the name `$array` but add stuff to a non-existing array named `$lname`. You should change the `$array = array();` to `$lname = array();`

Comment: It's not working. I didn't understand the jQuery part. And why is $lname data null? Sorry I'm new at jQuery

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding on the jQuery side? The `$lname` data is now filled with the name as the key and a value of null because the JSON format that the autocomplete expects is `{'name': 'image', ...}` or `{'name': null, ...}`. So you need an array that has the name as the key and either an image or a null as the value so that `json_encode` will create the correct JSON format from the array.

Comment: .done is not working. console says _Cannot read property 'done' of undefined_